# Why Use Deffie Hellmen(Key Exchange) instead of encrypting the symmetric session key with the servers's or client's public key?

Tags: ssh, encryption, public-key-encryption

If the client generates the symmetric session key and then encrypts in with the server's public key and send it to the server, then only the server can decrypt the encrypted session key with it's private key, vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such key exchange methods do exist – indeed for a long time this was the *primary* way that keys were exchanged in SSL/TLS, and a similar scheme was the only available exchange method within SSHv1 (which is now obsolete).

However, both systems have migrated *from* encryption-based key exchange to DH.

The mechanism you describe has one major problem: If the server's private key is stolen, it can be used to decrypt *every single connection* that was previously made or will ever be made with that key pair. (In other words, it **lacks [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)**.)

Considering that HTTPS certificates used to be issued for 5 or even 10 years, and SSH outright *relies* on the hostkeys not changing once created, this can be quite a risk. (For example, if the same attacker has been monitoring network traffic on the datacenter... or if you live in a country which participated in such surveillance programs as PRISM or XKeyscore.)

*(SSHv1 tried to mitigate this by generating ephemeral RSA keys for key-exchange purposes, but this completely negates the advantage of having a "known" server key to encrypt things with. And because RSA key generation requires a considerable amount of processing, it was done only every few hours and the ephemeral keys were limited to 768 bits.)*

The other problem is that requiring encryption capability **limits your choice of key algorithm**. If I understand correctly, asymmetric digital signatures (to authenticate the DH key exchange) are easier to implement than asymmetric encryption even for those algorithms which *could* do both – and not all can.

For example, EC keys cannot be used for encryption directly, only for signing and key exchange. There are schemes which implement encryption with EC keys (e.g. ECMQV), but they are actually *based on ECDH key exchange.* Might as well just use DH, then.

Comment: Efficiency also comes into play, as ECDHE-based ciphers are usually more efficient than non-ECDHE ciphers, especially when using TLS-based ciphers